# Parse DB - Lazy-evaluation on queries

Tags: parse-platform, lazy-evaluation

Does the Parse.com database engine have built in lazy evaluation for repeated queries?

For example, lets say I have a table with millions of rows and there is a column that must be summed several times per minute. Obviously one would not sum millions of values every time. Should I have a running total variable which is updated upon every row insertion, or would the repeated queries be handled with laziness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Parse, you should use counters and increment/decrement them based on other actions.  Count queries do not scale.

You can use before/afterSave triggers or other cloud functions, in Cloud Code, to modify these counters.

Comment: Do you have an example of a decrement? It keeps failing my application.

Comment: Failing how? It's an increment for -1

Comment: For some reason, it couldn't find the 'decrement' function in the object returned, though it can find the 'increment'. Ended up just updating it the old school way

Comment: there is no decrement function, you pass in a negative number as the second parameter.  object.increment('field', -1);

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. It'd be great for Parse to include in their docs -- at least at first seemed to me as they were saying there was a decrement function. Thank you!